# Discuss if function defined by $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}$ from set $A = [-1, 1]$ to itself is one-one, onto, or bijective.

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $A = [-1,1]$. Then discuss whether the following function from $A$ to itself is one-one, onto or bijective.
$f (x) = \frac{x}{2}$

Could someone tell what does $A$ to itself mean here? Does it mean $A \to f(A)$ or $A \to A$ or something else?

Comment: "A to itself" means that $f$ is only allowed to take values in A – it doesn't necessarily mean that its image is all of A, only that you won't see $f(x)=2$ (for example) when $x$ is in A.

Comment: If it meant $A \to f(A)$, then it would be, by definition, surjective. Not much to discuss (suggesting that $A \to A$ is really the one that is meant).

Answer (score 2):

It is not onto, since $\frac x2 = 1 \Longleftrightarrow x=2$ but $2 \notin A$.

It is injective, since $\frac{x}{2} = \frac{y}{2} \Longleftrightarrow x=y$

Comment: I assume you meant to write $2 \notin A$,  which you can produce by writing 2 \notin A in math mode.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yeah, thanks, that was  a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It means the domain is A and the co-domain is also A -- the co-domain is not necessarily the *range* of $f$.

Your function is clearly one-to-one on the set A, but it is not onto;

pick, for example, the number y = 1, which is in A.

Then, by the definition of $f$, we have 2 = x, which is not in A.

Comment: But $f$ does take irrational values? Take any irrational number in $[-1,1]$ and plug it in...

Comment: Ah, you are absolutely right, @QuinnGreicius.  I will edit my answer or possibly delete it if I cannot figure out whether $f$ is onto.  Thanks :-)

Comment: I just edited my answer @QuinnGreicius